# How to make borders align with sub headers?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a table like structure in `tkinter` using `grid` method. In my code i have 3 headers and 3 sub-headers, and each header must have three sub-headers under them. To achieve this i have used `columnspan` in `grid`. I am almost getting the required output but the only thing missing is that the borders (`relief = "groove"`) are not aligned with the three sub-headers under it.

I have tried to change the width of the `Label` but still they are not aligning.

How do i align the headers and sub-headers borders?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

headers = ["header_1","header_2","header_3"]
sub_headers = ["sub_header_1","sub_header_2","sub_header_3"]

c = 0
for i in headers:
    label = Label(root, text = i, width = 15, relief = "groove")
    label.grid(row = 0, column = c, columnspan = 3)
    c += 3

c = 0
count = 1
while count < 4:
    for j in sub_headers:
        label = Label(root, text = j, width = 15, relief = "groove")
        label.grid(row = 1, column = c)
        c += 1
    count += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `sticky` parameter:

```
...

for i in headers:
    label = Label(root, text = i, width = 15, relief = "groove")
    label.grid(row = 0, column = c, columnspan = 3, sticky="ew")
    c += 3
```